# how to do a search across many to many tables with rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, search, many-to-many

I have three tables containing details of moulds (molds) and their patterns linked together via a genres table :

```
Mould table
id : integer
name : string


Pattern table
id : integer
name : string

genres table
id : integer
mould_id :integer
pattern_id : integer
```

I have data in the tables as follows

```
Mould table
ID          Name
1           A1
2           A2
3           A3
53          A4
54          A5
197         A6
198         A7
1204        A8
1205        A9

Pattern Table

ID         Name
1          Running
2          Scroll

Genres Table

ID     mould_id  pattern_id
1       1           1
2       2           1
3       3           1
4       53          1
5       53          2
6       54          1
7       197         2
8       198         1
9       1204        2
10      1205        1
```

From my calcs, Moulds 53, 197 and 1204 all have a pattern of Scroll so I should be able to write the following SQL to give that

```
SELECT m.id   FROM moulds m INNER JOIN genres g
ON m.id = g.mould_id INNER JOIN patterns p
ON g.pattern_id = p.id  
WHERE p.id = 2     
GROUP BY m.id    
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
```

But it only returns 197  So something is wrong there (or with my data)

Then converting it to Rails I wrap it up in a find_by_sql which gives the same result (which makes sense)

Can someone help with the SQL or suggest a better, rails way of doing this sort of query?

Comment: I've tested what you have here, and it works for me (returns the three moulds you mention). The only difference with my test was that I used `mould_ids` ranging from 1 to 9 (mapping 53 to 4, 54 to 5, etc.). So I suspect there is something strange going on with your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the models and data that you have above and I get the result you expect (i.e. the three moulds with names "A4", "A6" and "A8"). So I suspect something is going on with your data.

That aside, I'd suggest using Rails [query methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to get the desired data rather than resorting to SQL. For example, this:

```
Mould.select('moulds.id')\
     .joins(:patterns)\
     .where('patterns.id' => 2)\
     .group('moulds.id')\
     .having('COUNT(*) >= ?', 1)
```

will generate this SQL:

```
SELECT moulds.id FROM "moulds"
INNER JOIN "genres" ON "genres"."mould_id" = "moulds"."id"
INNER JOIN "patterns" ON "patterns"."id" = "genres"."pattern_id"
WHERE "patterns"."id" = 2
GROUP BY moulds.id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
```

This is pretty much the same as the SQL you have, and produces the same result (again, the correct one with three results).

Note that the `INNER JOIN genres g` part of your SQL comes out here without explicitly mentioning it. This works as long as you have `through` associations defined on `Mould` and `Pattern`:

```
class Mould < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :genres
  has_many :patterns, :through => :genres
  #...
end

class Pattern < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :genres
  has_many :moulds, :through => :genres
  #...
end
```

Since you tell Rails that `Mould` and `Pattern` are associated through the `genres` table, it knows how to build the correct SQL query to join them together.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Shioyama.  Many thanks for your response.  Ive flagged it as the right answer as it really helped with the rails way of doing things, rather than resorting to SQL. Although I still get only one result when run with my data, and the sample I posted was just a subset of the records.  Not sure where things are going wrong here. Thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome! Not sure what's going wrong either, like I said I actually entered the data you posted and ran the query on it, and it worked. The only thing that I changed were the ids on moulds, which I mapped to 1-9. What if you just try testing on a clean database?

Comment: It's also possible that the result you get has something to do with the type of database you are using. I tested in sqlite3.

Comment: Definitely something wrong with the data.  Working against a clean set of data and it gives the expected result. Time to dig through the old data more. Thanks for the help.